# should i store user specific information for other entity in my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to access http APIs of a server from lambda function. But this http api expect some encrypted credential information ( lets say token) in headers. For every user, there is unique token generated. Should i store this token for each user using some db like dynamoDB.

Is it a good practice?
or, Is there any service which can be used for user management
or else, what can i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to store it somewhere, and I guess you will probably need to load user information anyway so you might as well store it with that, where-ever that might be.

Of course, it is important that you keep all your user information secure and keeping it all in one place, including this access token, makes it easier to keep it secure, as opposed to storing it separately from your other user info.

And yes DynamoDB is a very common choice for storing user info on AWS.  Slower then SQL options, but still a good and common choice.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Also, if you have a new question you should post it separately.